# Regex to match domain failing on input

Tags: php, regex, match

I created a regex to match the domain name out of the input:

```
$pattern = '/\w+\..{2,3}(?:\..{2,3})?(?:$|(?=\/))/i';
$url = 'http://wwe.com';
if (preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches) === 1) {
    echo $matches[0];
}
```

It works fine for this input:

```
http://google.com // output:google.com
```

But I am not able to achieve it for these inputs: (if the user enters an extra `www`

```
http://www.google.com // output:google.com
http://www.www.google.com // output:google.com
```

What am I missing?

Any help on this will be appreciated

Comment: Why not use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url)?

Comment: @drew010 I don't want to return an array

Comment: Just return $url['host'] and let it do the parsing for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
<?php

$urls = [
    'http://google.com',
    'http://www.google.com',
    'http://www.www.google.com',
];

foreach($urls as $url) {
    $url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $url = preg_replace('/^(www\.)+/', '', $url);
    echo $url . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
google.com
google.com
www.google.com
```

Comment: My main issue is the last output of yours. I need it to match the other outputs so no www at all

Comment: Edited to remove multiple `www.` from the beginning of the url.